# What is the correct name of H2SO2? Sulphoxylic acid or hyposulphuric acid

Tags: nomenclature

Given the oxidation state on S, it seems the correct name should be hyposulphurous acid, but I have seen multiple sources call it sulphoxylic acid, or both
What is the reasoning behind this nomeculture

Comment: Fairly likely that sulphoxylic acid is the old non-systematic name that chemists got used to using - like acetic/ethanoic acid - and is used in older literature.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfoxylic_acid) names the compound as sulfoxylic acid and the other name provided is hyposulfurous acid

Comment: Pretty much *any* compound can be named in different ways, and it doesn't mean one of them is "correct".

Comment: Also depends on locale: US has *sulfur*, but British likely import all their *sulphur*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sulfoxylic_acid) lists "sulfoxylic acid" first, so that appears to be the preferred name. There are isomers with the same formula $\ce{H2SO2}$ and sulfur in the oxidation state +2, so "hyposulfurous acid" based on the oxygen content may be considered less specific than "sulfoxylic acid".

Unlike what is apparently the case for sulfurous/sulfonic acid and phophorous/phosphonic acid, the most stable isomer of  $\ce{H2SO2}$ seems to be the one with all hydrogens attached to oxygen, thus the sulfoxylic acid isomer.

Many uncommon anions are known with relatively benign alkali-metal cations, but not sulfoxylate. The referenced Wikipedia article reports instead that sulfoxylates have been synthesized with late transition elements (cobalt, copper(I)) or post-transition elements (zinc, thallium(I)). No explanation is given for this apparent preference. Possibly sulfoxylates of these metals draw more interest because they may come up in the roasting of sulfide ores.